# Azure only allows Verisign certificates

Tags: azure

I am looking to install a certificate on my Azure hosted site but from what I can see they only accept Verisign certificates. This is unfortunate as Verisign is very expensive. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was answered on the Windows Azure MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuresecurity/thread/cbc96ef9-d5cf-42db-a968-928c805f5a56

> Hello, I'll list the CA installed on the cloud machines for DigiCert and Go Daddy:
>
> DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
>
> DigiCert Global Root CA
>
> DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
>
> Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
>
> So in most cases, your existing certificates should work fine.

Comment: Note that in the linked thread the OP only asked about DigiCert and GoDaddy so that's why the answer covers those two.  Most likely many more are supported.